# How to set the uipanel size in matlab and add slider in the uipanel?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider

I Wanna display the output messeges in the uipanel in matlab GUI.
and if i use this code,

```
  hp1 = uipanel('Title','UI Panel 1',...
  'Position', [157.6  30.308  62.4  12.615]);

  uicontrol(...
  'Parent', hp1,...
   'Style','text',...
   'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0 0 1 1],...
   'String', psancitra1);
```

the size and the position of the uipanel is so big and located in the center of window.

How to set the position, the size(width,long) of the uipanel?

and how to add a slider in the uipanel, so if the messeges line (**psancitra1**) is more than the size of the uipanel, we can use the scoll bar?

Thank you for the help before :D

Answer (score 1):

> How to set the position, the size(width,long) of the uipanel?

With 'Position', [left bottom width height] you define where your uicontrol is placed. You should also check the parameter Units.

For example like this:

```
    h=figure;
    hp1 = uipanel('Parent', h,'Units','Normalized','Title','UI Panel 1',...
    'Position', [0 0 .5 0.3]);  
    uicontrol('Parent', hp1,'Style','text',...
    'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0 0 0.5 1],...
    'String', 'psancitra1');
```

You can also check the documentation at mathworks:
[matlab: uicontrol properties-> position](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoipv)

Comment: So, the position of the uipanel never always in range 0>position<=1, is it right?

Comment: well, with "Units,"Normalized" the parameters of position are in relation to the parent control, where [0 0 1 1] is equal to the size of the parent. [1.5 0 1 1] would be 1.5*starting-point-left, so your parameters can get bigger then 1, but in this case they will be somewhere outside\bigger then its parent control. (if this solves your second question?)